# Printing a value each iteration of a while loop

Tags: c++, loops

I must calculate experience needed for the level the user inputs then print that level and each level before it with the amount of experience needed like this:

Level 1 requires 0 experience.
Level 2 requires 100 experience.
Level 3 requires 400 experience.

so on and so forth.

experience = 100 * (level - 1) * (level - 1)

I have this so far but I do not know how to print all of the levels instead of just the one the user input.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib> 
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    double level;
    double experience = 0;

    cout << "What levels do you want to know the experience needed for?" << endl;
    cout << endl;
    cin >> level;
    while (level != 0) {
        experience = 100 * (level - 1) * (level - 1);
        cout << endl;
        cout << "Level " << " " << level << " needs " << " " << experience << " experience." << endl;
        break;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

If user input is 4 just Level 4 with needed expeience prints.
I need all the levels up to and including level 4 to print, or whichever level number user inputs.

Comment: 1. Your `break` will exit the loop after one iteration. 2. Using `for` loop might be more convenient in this case.

Comment: Could you add to your question an explanation of why you think your code should work? (Why did you write the code this way? How do you expect your current loop to proceed?)

Answer (score 1):

Write a `for` loop

```
for (int i = 1; i <= level; ++i)
{
    experience = 100 * (i - 1) * (i - 1);
    cout << endl;
    cout << "Level " << i << " needs " << experience << " experience."<< endl;
}
```

Whenever you need a loop that executes a known number of times you generally write a `for` loop, with a *loop control variable* that indicates which iteration you are currently on (that's the variable `i` in this case).